# Python suds client and not standard service name

Tags: python, web-services, soap, wsdl, client-server

Look at this example:

```
from suds.client import Client
url = 'http://xxx.yy.com/etc...'
client = Client(url)
result = client.service.wsExtAuth..ckAuth(username='xx')
```

The service "wsExtAuth..ckAuth" is not standard (name) and compiler return syntax error. How can I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
getattr(client.service, 'wsExtAuth..ckAuth')(username='xx')
```

Also, make sure you're using [`suds-jurko`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/suds-jurko) and not the outdated `suds` client.

Comment: ok, now it response `not well-formed (invalid token)` but using php it works:

`$client = new SoapClient( $url );
$result = $client->__soapCall("wsExtAuth..ckAuth",array('username'=>'xx')`